# jQuery selector execute after view is rendered in backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jquery-selectors, view

I want to execute jQuery selectors after backbone view is rendered and template is appended to DOM. How to do that if my view isn't rendered in initialize method?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but here is my best shot.  The view has a property `$` which can be accessed from your render method by using `this.$`. For example:

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        //do some stuff
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$("#selector").find() // a jQuery selector scoped to the view's el
    }
})
```